# SQL Server: group by to retrieve rows with 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a query which retrieves a list of count grouped by month as below

```
 SELECT 
     CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 1 THEN 'January'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 2 then 'February'                         
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 3 then 'March'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 4 then 'April'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 5 then 'May'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 6 then 'June'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 7 then 'July'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 8 then 'August'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 9 then 'September'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 10 then 'October'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 11 then 'November'
        WHEN MONTH(StartDate) = 12 then 'December' 
        ELSE '' 
     END AS [month],
     COUNT(*) AS Count
 FROM
     Users
 WHERE
     YEAR(StartDate) = '2018'
 GROUP BY
     MONTH(StartDate)
 ORDER BY 
     MONTH(StartDate)
```

The result looks something like this:

```
Month    | Count
---------+-------
January  |   1
February |   2
April    |   7
May      |   3
```

As you can see there are missing months on the list which id like to retrieve.
Expected result:

```
Month    | Count
---------+-------
January  |   1
February |   2
March    |   0
April    |   7
May      |   3
June     |   0
```

Etc...

How can I get the months with zero count?

Comment: Why don't you just use `DATENAME(MONTH, StartDate) AS Month` instead of that big, unwieldy `CASE`  expression.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make a calendar table then do `outer join` it.

and move condition `YEAR(StartDate) = '2018'` to `ON` from `WHERE` , because you need to use `OUTER JOIN`

and just `order by startnum` column.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 1 startnum,12 endnum
   UNION ALL
   SELECT startnum +1 ,endnum
   FROM CTE 
   where startnum +1  <= endnum
)
SELECT 
     t1.dt as [month],
     Count(Users.StartDate) as Count
 FROM (
    SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, startnum - 1, CAST('1900-01-01' AS date))) dt,startnum
    FROM CTE 
 ) t1 LEFT JOIN  Users on t1.startnum = MONTH(StartDate) AND YEAR(StartDate) = '2018'
 GROUP by t1.dt,t1.startnum
 ORDER BY t1.startnum
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba11e6f43e01fa2c055ecf8aa5e8dedb)

Comment: Hi - I just tried your example and it retrieves a list but the months with zeros are still missing

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @MishMish No problem glad to help :)

Comment: Btw the order by is not working properly, can't seem to know why? https://prnt.sc/li8wst

Comment: @MishMish If order by name of month it will order by the character I edit my answer :)

Comment: Great! and i promise this is my last question. If I have more filters id like to add into my "Where Clause" Where do i enter them, after the left join?

Comment: try to move your condition to `on` from original put in `where`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` construct & do `left join` :

```
SELECT mm.month, count(q.Count)
FROM ( VALUES ('January'), . . . , ('December') 
     ) mm (month) LEFT JOIN
     ( <query> 
     ) q
     ON q.month = mm.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of month start dates and use those in the query:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2018-01-01' as date) as dte, 1 as num
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte), num + 1
      from dates
      where num < 12
     )
select year(d.dte), datename(month, d.dte), count(u.startdate)
from dates d left join
     users u
     on month(u.startdate) >= month(d.dte)
where u.startdate >= '2018-01-01' and
      u.startdate < '2019-01-01' 
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

This generates the months using a recursive CTE.  Note some of the other changes:

- The year is explicitly included throughout the query, to ensure that the query continues to do what you expect even if expand the date range.
- The date range is defined using a range, rather than `year()`.  This is a best practice, so the query can take advantage of indexes.
- There is no need for a `case` expression, because date functions can extract the month name.